# select the data structure in perl

Tags: perl

I have to store the below data in a structure in perl!

```
{
mo=>RXOTG-12,
a=>1,
b=>2,
c=>3,
    {
     mo=>RXOTRX-12,
     d=>4,
     e=>5,
         {
         mp=>RXOTX-12,
         f=>6,
         g=>7
         }
    },
    {
     mo=>RXOMCTR-12,
     i=>8,
     j=>9
    },
k=>10   
}
```

Could anybody please tell me what is the best data structure which is suitable for this.
hash of a has is not suitable for this as there are some individial elements too like a,b,c  as mentioned in the example.

Answer (score 1):

Use a hash.

If a piece of data is a scalar (like `a`) then make the value of `a` a scalar.

If it is a hash, then make it a hashref.

There is no requirement that the value of every key in a hash be the same type of data structure.

Give names to the data structures that come between `c` and `k` or bring the data in them up a level.

Answer (score 1):

Very little is missing:

```
{
mo=>RXOTG-12,
a=>1,
b=>2,
c=>3,
children => [             <---
    {
     mo=>RXOTRX-12,
     d=>4,
     e=>5,
     children => [        <---
         {
         mp=>RXOTX-12,
         f=>6,
         g=>7
         }
     ],                   <---
    },
    {
     mo=>RXOMCTR-12,
     i=>8,
     j=>9
    },
],                        <---
k=>10   
}
```